# Concatenate matrices (each matrix is a sum of two)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that $A=[A_1 \ A_2 \  A_3] \in \mathbb{R}^{I_1 \times I_2 \cdot I_3}$, where $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{I_1 \times I_2}$ for $i=1,2,3$ ($I_3=3 \ $ in this case).

Given a matrix  $B=[B_1 \ B_2 \  B_3] \in \mathbb{R}^{I_1 \times I_2 \cdot I_3}$, where $B_i = A_i + C_i \in \mathbb{R}^{I_1 \times I_2}$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $C_i$ is an error.

I can rewrite $B$ as
$$B=[(A_1 + C_1) \  \ (A_2 + C_2) \  \  (A_3 + C_3)]$$

Is it possible to resolve?

I am looking for how to present $B$ using $A$? Is it possible to resolve?

Comment: Can you simply write $B = A + C$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom and $C $ is a matrix of $C_i$:$ [C_1 \  \ C_2 \ \ C_3]$?

Comment: Yes, exactly.${}$